# Javascript multidimensional array, moving its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to move array cells right,left,top,up. I will try to show that on example.

```
var ar = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```

its like [0][0] is 1 // [0][1] is 2 // [0][2] is 3 ... [2][2] is 9

I am looking for possibility to move their value, this way:
[0][0] will be undefined // [0][1] will be 1  // [0][2] will be 2 ... [2][2] will be 8.

I would like that [X][Y][Z] X will be at Y place, Y will be at Z place, Z will create next cell.

I am sorry if I explained this bad, its my first question here. Thanks all for help anyway.

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: Sorry, but I've been trying to do it different ways, noone seems to work. I don't see the point of uploading totally bad code which doesn't work at all.

Comment: Please share your effort regardless, so that we can have a look at how bad it is and help you improve upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first item of each sub-array should be `undefined`, then use `map` and `unshift`

```
ar.map( s => s.unshift(undefined) )
```

**Note**

- Answer assumes that you want to mutate the array since you mentioned *I am looking for possibility to move their value*

If ar shouldn't be mutated, then

```
var output = ar.map( s => ( 
    a  = s.slice(), 
    a.unshift(undefined), 
    a ) );
```

Comment: I didn't know before that something like map existed. I found some informations about it, it may seem to be answer for my question. I'm going to dig a little more about it. thanks!